# Relationship between a hasMany and belongsToMany in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two Models - InternalNotesThread and InternalNotes

```
class InternalNotesThread extends Model {

public function notes(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\InternalNotes', 'thread_id', 'id');
    }
}

class InternalNotes extends Model {

public function thread() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\InternalNotesThread');
    }
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_notes_tagged', 'internal_notes_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Also, InternalNotes is mapped to User with a relation of belongsToMany.

DB Structure:

```
internal_notes_thread:
id - int
ticket_id (FK) - int
name - string

internal_notes:
id - int
thread_id (FK) - int
notes - string

user_notes_tagged: (Many to many with internal_notes and User)
internal_notes_id (FK) - int
user_id (FK) - int
```

For every note, there might be some user tagged in it.

How can I directly relate this relationship with the internal_notes_thread???

I get the data with this:

```
$data = InternalNotesThread::with('notes')->where('ticket_id', '=', $id)->get()->toArray();
```

But, in the **notes** array, I am not able to get the users tagged in that note

How can I get all the data in one go???

Comment: Sorry, typo error. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not eager loading the users, so they don't show up in your `->toArray()` array.

Try this:

```
$data = InternalNotesThread::with('notes.users')
    ->where('ticket_id', '=', $id)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: What if I want to get only user_id from the User table. Currently it shows me all the fields.

Comment: See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads -- something like `->with('notes.users' => function ($query) { $query->select(['id']); })`

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But, it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Post a new question about this with some details and I'll see if I can help.